# When monitoringDidFailForRegion method is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

After calling `startMonitoringForRegion`  `[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];` then its delegate methods are called.

When region monitoring starts successfully then `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:`  delegate method is called.

But if region monitoring **do not** starts successfully then is this method is called `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:` ?

If not then when `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:` is called?

Comment: You can get that details here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423720-locationmanager

Comment: Yes I did read the Doc but still confused.

Comment: What is your confusion ? If region monitoring is successfully registered it will call the `didStartMonitoringForRegion` else `monitoringDidFailForRegion` will be called

Comment: Am I right or wrong?

Comment: It's very unfortunate that you couldn't understand what I said in my previous comment. *But if region monitoring do not starts successfully then is this method is called locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError: ?* Yes, you are correct

Comment: The docs say "Region monitoring might fail because the region itself cannot be monitored or because there was a more general failure in configuring the region monitoring service.". It would be interesting to know 1) why a region cannot be monitored and 2) which configuration failures can happen.

Comment: I found one possible reason: If the value of the monitoring radius is larger than the `maximumRegionMonitoringDistance` property of the locationManager, monitoring will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when your app doesn't have location access set to always I had the same issue I fixed it by doing the below.

1st make sure you have these in your info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string> Explain why?</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string> Explain why?</string>
```

2nd tell the location manager you want location access always, this makes sense since you monitoring regions like below.

locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

If you do the above correctly then your region monitoring shouldn't fail